# Ocupar en Redis forEach para hacer varias consultas a API [NodeJS][Express

Tags: nodejs, api, express, promesas, redis

Resulta que he estado intentando de varias maneras poder resolver ésto. Es fácil ocupar redis y hacer una consulta con fetch a una api que posee un array de datos. 
Pero se complica cuando deseo hacer varias consultas a una API con id's diferentes.

Para obtener mi JSON principal tengo éste link 
https://simple.ripley.cl/api/v2/products/sku
Donde sku es mi id y es distinto para cada producto. La finalidad inicial de mi App es obtener de 25 sku, 25 json distintos y guardarlos en redis, para luego ser usado en el Front con React.

Éste es mi server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient(6379);

client.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log('Error' + err)
});

app.get('/products',(req,res)=>{
    const productsRedisKey = 'user:products';
    var randomSKU = [2000375935929, 2000372817877, 2000371995293, 2000367524094, 2000373649262,
        2000372006813, 2000349155957, 2000375977097, 2000372464781, 2000373649477, 2000375935998,
        2000372209085, 2000367524537, 2000373941724, 2000372014238, 2000373730847, 2000372010599,
        2000372013897, 2000375935509, 2000373664098, 2000375977189, 2000375936063, 2000372026453,
        2000370790707, 2000373941656];
    var randomArraySKU = randomSKU.map((sku => {
            fetch(`https://simple.ripley.cl/api/v2/products/${sku}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(product => {
                console.log(product.partNumber);
                return product
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return res.json(error.toString())
            })
        }));
    console.log('from server: randomArraySKU');
    console.log(randomArraySKU);
    return (
            client.get(productsRedisKey,(error,products)=>{
                if(products){
                    return res.json({
                        source: 'cache',
                        data: JSON.parse(products)
                    })
                }else {
                    client.setex(productsRedisKey, 60, JSON.stringify(randomArraySKU))
                    return res.json({
                        source: 'api',
                        data: products
                    })
                }
            })
        )

});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('server on port 3000')
});
```

Me sale el siguiente resultado en la consola

```
from server: randomArraySKU
[
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined
]
2000373649262
2000349155957
2000367524537
2000375935509
2000375977189
2000375936063
2000373664098
2000372464781
2000372006813
2000373941656
2000375935929
2000372817877
2000373649477
2000372026453
2000367524094
2000375935998
2000375977097
2000373730847
2000372013897
2000373941724
2000372014238
2000372010599
2000372209085
2000370790707
2000371995293
from server: randomArraySKU
[
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined
]
2000371995293
2000373649262
2000372817877
2000375935929
2000372006813
2000367524094
2000349155957
2000373664098
2000372014238
2000372464781
2000375977097
2000372209085
2000373941724
2000373649477
2000372013897
2000373730847
2000375935998
2000375935509
2000372010599
2000375977189
2000373941656
2000370790707
2000375936063
2000367524537
2000372026453
from server: randomArraySKU
[
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined
]
2000372464781
2000375935998
2000372209085
2000375977097
2000349155957
2000373649262
2000373649477
2000372013897
2000372014238
2000373730847
2000372006813
2000373941724
2000375936063
2000372010599
2000367524537
2000372026453
2000375977189
2000373941656
2000373664098
2000375935509
2000370790707
2000367524094
2000375935929
2000372817877
2000371995293
```

Answer (score 0):

me tomé la libertad de modificar tu codigo...

si bien lo que intentas hacer tiene la logica casi correcta, esta hecha de una forma casi incorrecta.

```
app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    const productsRedisKey = 'user:products';

    var randomSKU = [2000375935929, 2000372817877, 2000371995293, 2000367524094, 2000373649262,
        2000372006813, 2000349155957, 2000375977097, 2000372464781, 2000373649477, 2000375935998,
        2000372209085, 2000367524537, 2000373941724, 2000372014238, 2000373730847, 2000372010599,
        2000372013897, 2000375935509, 2000373664098, 2000375977189, 2000375936063, 2000372026453,
        2000370790707, 2000373941656];

    Promise
        .all(randomSKU.map(sku => {
            return fetch(`https://simple.ripley.cl/api/v2/products/${sku}`).then(response => response.json());
        }))
        .then(productList => {
            client.get("user:products", (error, products) => {
                if (!error && products) {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        source: "cache",
                        data: JSON.parse(products),
                    })
                } else {
                    client.setex("user:products", 60, JSON.stringify(productList))
                    res.status(200).json({
                        source: "api",
                        data: productList
                    })
                }
            })
        })
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server on port 3000')
});
```